# python map function iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

results is a nested list, and looks like this:

```
>>> results
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd'], [4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b'], [4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd']]
```

pr is a function, with definition like this:

```
>>> def pr(line):
...     print line
```

Normal iteration on results does behaves like this:

```
>>> for result in results:
...     pr(result)
... 
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']
[1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd']
[4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b']
[4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd']
```

But implicit iteration with map, results in this behaviour:

```
>>> map(pr, results)
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']
[1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd']
[4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b']
[4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd']
[None, None, None, None]
```

**My question**:  Why does map function produce the additional iteration?

Comment: `map` comes from functional programming languages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29 It is not supposed to be used like this

Comment: @jamylak : pr is a demo function for this question, I was applying some other transformation in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` applies a function to each element of the iterable and the result of that is stored back in a list (or map object in Python 3). So the `[None, None, None, None]` part is the return value of the map function. You won’t see this when you execute a script, but you can also get rid of it in IDLE by just assigning it to a value:

```
>>> _ = map(pr, results)
```

Note though, that the construction of the result list (at least in Python 2) has some impact, so if you don’t need the result, you’re better off not using `map` in this case.

Answer (score 5):

`map` in Python 2 returns a list, built up of all the return values of the function you pass it. Your `pr` function returns `None` (implicitly, by falling off the end). So, the result of `map` will be a list filled with `None`s, one for each object in the iterable you pass in. This gets printed automatically by the interactive interpreter, since you didn't assign it to a variable - that is the last line you're seeing.

You can see this more clearly when you do assign it to a variable:

```
>>> a = map(pr, results)
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']
[1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd']
[4, 5, 6, 'a', 'b']
[4, 5, 6, 'c', 'd']
>>> a
[None, None, None, None]
```

Do note that using `map` when you don't care about this result wlil generally make your code harder to read; and using it for side effects even more so. In both these cases, it is preferable to write the explicit loop.

Answer (score 3):

`[None, None, None, None]` is the result of the call to `map`, which is printed automatically in the Python interpreter console.